# Best open source sql table viewer component for Eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, sql, eclipse-plugin, widget, resultset

I would like to write an Eclipse plugin for my open source project [1] with a property view that shows the content of a table. That table might come from an SQL database (e.g. SqLite or MySql). **Is there a nice open source "SQL table view component/widget" I can use for my eclipse plugin?**

Ideally the component would look **similar to** the table view of **Navicat** or **MySqlWorkbench** (see screen shot below [4]),
including

- a limit for the number of rows and the possibility to **navigate the rows with pages** ("go to page 2 to show the next 500 records")
- a way to filter/sort the contents of the table, for example by showing a **small sql editor** on top of the table, including the current query ("SELECT * FROM mytable" or "SELECT id FROM mytable")
- a first column including "row headers" to show a **row number**. (Not every table view supports row headers... )
- a way to automatically **adapt to the table structure**. If the sql result set contains for example five columns, those five columns should be automatically created for the table view.

[image: Image source: [5]]

There seem to bee some options out there (see below). Before evaluating

- which of them provides a nice **API** I can use in my own eclipse plugin
- which of them is **out dated**
- which of them has remaining **issues/bugs**

... I would like to ask you for **your experiences and recommendations**. What are pros and cons and what is the best open source SQL table viewer component you already used?

Possible **candidates** I found so far:

- ResultViewControl from Eclipse DTP project: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Results_View_Control
- Eclipse SQL Explorer: http://eclipsesql.sourceforge.net/
- JFaceDbc: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jfacedbc/
- QuantumDB Eclipse plugin: http://quantum.sourceforge.net/
- DBeaver: http://dbeaver.jkiss.org

If I start from scratch I basically would prefer a solution that is based on JFace. If required I could also try to include a JavaFx TableView [2] or a component like the Nebula Grid Widget [3]. If you know **alternative table view components** which I could use for my SQL table viewer, please let me know, too.

---

[1] Treez: http://sourceforge.net/projects/treez/

[2] Show SQL data in JavaFx TableView: [How to fill up a TableView with database data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18941093/how-to-fill-up-a-tableview-with-database-data)

[3] Nebula Grid Widget (supporting row headers): https://eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/grid/grid.php

[4] Image source for screen shot: [How to view table contents in Mysql Workbench GUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18644812/how-to-view-table-contents-in-mysql-workbench-gui)

Comment: This question seems more suited for http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Related questions about paging: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481138/how-to-provide-pagination-support-to-a-jtable-in-swing  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17261335/how-to-implement-paging-for-a-tableview-in-javafx